# Why isn't working this bounce effect in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, effect, bounce

Why isn't working the effect? `We`, `Members` and `Listen` are headers which redirect you to another page and my intention was to make them bouncing when your mouse is on one of these buttons.

HTML:

```
 <a id="asd" class="asd" href="a.html">We</a>
<a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
<a id="asd" class="asd" href="b.html">Members</a>
<a id="asd" class="asd" href="c.html">Listen</a>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".asd").mouseenter(function(){
         $(".asd").effect( "bounce", 
          {times:3}, 300 );
      });
 });
```

Comment: Do you already included jquery ui library??

Comment: Yes I did included jquery ui library

Comment: see this fiddle, your code is working http://jsfiddle.net/3jd2e0t5/1/

Comment: this code is working https://jsfiddle.net/06ar1jgx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hover/mouseenter for animation is finnicky, but at least you'll have more control using CSS. Try this?

```
.asd{
    position: relative
}

.asd:hover{
    animation: bounceText .5s;
    -webkit-animation: bounceText .5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceText {
    0%     {top: 0px;}
    50% {top: 10px;}
    100%   {top: 0px;}
}

@keyframes bounceText {
    0%     {top: 0px;}
    50% {top: 10px;}
    100%   {top: 0px;}
}
```